# How to find out the reason for rejection of a G-suite publish?

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish my App to G-Suite Marketplace via "G-suite Marketplace SDK Publish".  I believe I've followed all the steps, and read the help files.  But after I clicked publish, after a few days the status changed to "Unpublished (Rejected)" - with no further information.  I didn't get an e-mail either.  I tried once more (after making sure everything looked good) - but again, the status changed to the same, and no further information was provided.  **Very frustrating.**
Can anyone let me know where I can find out more information about what is happening with my submission?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a reason and publish the g suite app. I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing would be to [create an issue in the G Suite Marketplace issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191597&template=823910). They would need to check your app's specific details/state.

Answer (score 0):

When rejected, you will receive an email from Google Workspace Marketplace Reviews Team gwm-review@google.com that list all reasons that why your app is rejected so you can correct them.